# strip the text between second and third occurrence of slash using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How do i Extract text between second and third occurrence of slash using XSLT1.0 . I need to extract "abc" from the url "/aaaa/abc/bbbb/" . Tried `xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after('/aaaa/abc/bbbb','/'),'/'),'/')"/></h2>`

Comment: It might be a typo in your question, but you have missed out a closing apostrophe at the end of `'/aaaa/abc/bbbb`

Comment: Yes it was a typo

Comment: @user3276594 It should be working the way you have it (if you add the starting `<` to `xsl:value-of`).